# Are questions about flavor acceptable?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

With a lot of games, and particuarly in this scenario, Magic the Gathering, flavor is an aspect of the game that doesn't directly deal with the game play, but it has a big impact on the overall enjoyability of the game for some people.

If you're wondering what flavor is, it's what makes a card fit into a world or a story. For example, in the history of magic, every single spider printed (except for [one very old card](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2976)) has some kind of hate towards flying creatures. Why? Because spider webs catch flies, of course! Another example of flavor would be [Mogg Flunkies](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=249706) - they're bigger than they should be for their cost, but they can't attack by themselves. Why? Well the flavor is they need someone smart enough to tell them what to attack, because they're really, really dumb.

The flavor of things isn't just in the cards, but often in the game itself. Magic doesn't have a deck, it has a "library". There's no discard pile, there's a "graveyard". These are all considered forms of flavor.

My question is: are questions that enquire about flavor permitted on BCG? Example questions might be "What is the flavor of Planeswalkers going to the graveyard?" or "What is the flavor behind [Forced Fruition](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Forced%20Fruition)?".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have no objection to questions about flavor as long as they meet the other criteria of a good question. From [What Type of Questions Should I Avoid Asking](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

I'm not familiar enough with your examples to judge them as questions without seeing potential answers. I'm a bit worried about the questions not really being answerable and/or falling under the "chatty, open-ended" clause, but I don't know.

**Questions about flavor are fine; they should be judged based on the same criteria as any other question.**

I know there's quite an extensive "lore" for MtG, and if someone started asking questions about plot points that are best accessed through books, I might advise them to use the SciFi/Fantasy Stack Exchange instead. I think an analogous situation would be if someone asked questions about, say, making a custom table for board gaming. I think a lot of questions about its functionality and design would be on-topic here, but if they started asking what kind of glue to use for the joints there's probably a construction or DIY stack exchange better suited.

Comment: I agree with this. Flavour in and of itself is not taboo, but I think it will be difficult to come up with reasonable questions based on flavour alone. Most questions of the form "What is the flavour of X?" are very easy, and fail the bar for adequate research, IMHO. There are also a very large number of them.